# Python list of first day of month for given period

Tags: python, list

I am trying find an efficient way of creating a list of dates only including the first day of the month for a given period. Something like this but better:

```
import datetime
dates = [
  datetime.date (2014, 4, 1),
  datetime.date (2014, 5, 1),
  datetime.date (2014, 6, 1),
  datetime.date (2014, 7, 1),
  datetime.date (2014, 8, 1),
  datetime.date (2014, 9, 1),
  datetime.date (2014, 10, 1),
  datetime.date (2014, 11, 1),
  datetime.date (2014, 12, 1),
  datetime.date (2015, 1, 1),
  datetime.date (2015, 2, 1)]
```

Alternatively, some direction on what to Google for this. Cheers!

Comment: How the date period is given ? 2 `datetime.date` objects ?

Comment: Whatever is easier, I'm working on a iPython notebook and my code looked ridiculous with that array :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> startyear = 2014
>>> startmonth = 4
>>> endyear = 2015
>>> endmonth = 2
>>> [datetime.date(m/12, m%12+1, 1) for m in xrange(startyear*12+startmonth-1, endyear*12+endmonth)]
[datetime.date(2014, 4, 1), datetime.date(2014, 5, 1), datetime.date(2014, 6, 1), datetime.date(2014, 7, 1), datetime.date(2014, 8, 1), datetime.date(2014, 9, 1), datetime.date(2014, 10, 1), datetime.date(2014, 11, 1), datetime.date(2014, 12, 1), datetime.date(2015, 1, 1), datetime.date(2015, 2, 1)]
```

For Python 3, you'll need to use `range` instead of `xrange`, and `//` ([floor division](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)) instead of `/` (which does float division in Python 3):

```
[datetime.date(m//12, m%12+1, 1) for m in range(startyear*12+startmonth-1, endyear*12+endmonth)]
```

Comment: I agree with Andrew on this one (except for the bruteforce) - this is imo. too complex.

Comment: I'll be sure to ask codereview.stackexchange next time.

Comment: There's no reason to get grumpy when someone disagrees with your solution to a particular problem. You don't even have to reply if don't feel like it.

Answer (score 22):

With pandas :

```
   dates= pd.date_range('2018-01-01','2020-01-01' , freq='1M')-pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
```

result :

```
`DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-04-01',
               '2018-05-01', '2018-06-01', '2018-07-01', '2018-08-01',
               '2018-09-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-11-01', '2018-12-01',
               '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-04-01',
               '2019-05-01', '2019-06-01', '2019-07-01', '2019-08-01',
               '2019-09-01', '2019-10-01', '2019-11-01', '2019-12-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

Comment: Nice, but you should specify that it will includes the start of the range (that is '2018-01-01') but not the end (i.e. '2020-01-01')

Answer (score 8):

If you're only creating the list for a few years then efficiency should not be a concern. Clarity of code is the most important aspect.

```
dates = []
date = datetime.date.today()
while date.year < 2015:
    if date.day == 1:
        dates.append(date)
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Yes, this will handle the case of leap years (when we skip a year).

Answer (score 6):

Try pandas.date_range() with the 'MS' (Month Start) frequency alias:

```
import pandas as pd

start = '2020-01-01'
end = '2020-12-01'

dates = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='MS')

print(dates)
```

Result:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-04-01',
               '2020-05-01', '2020-06-01', '2020-07-01', '2020-08-01',
               '2020-09-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-11-01', '2020-12-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

A list of all frequency aliases can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases).

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to bruteforce this:

```
import datetime
from pprint import pprint

dt = datetime.date.today()
end = datetime.date(2015, 2, 1)
dates = []

while dt < end:
    if not dt.month % 12:
        dt = datetime.date(dt.year+1, 1, 1)
    else:
        dt = datetime.date(dt.year, dt.month+1, 1)
    dates.append(dt)

pprint(dates)
```

Output:

```
[datetime.date(2014, 4, 1),
 datetime.date(2014, 5, 1),
 datetime.date(2014, 6, 1),
 datetime.date(2014, 7, 1),
 datetime.date(2014, 8, 1),
 datetime.date(2014, 9, 1),
 datetime.date(2014, 10, 1),
 datetime.date(2014, 11, 1),
 datetime.date(2014, 12, 1),
 datetime.date(2015, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2015, 2, 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use relativedelta from dateutil, and then create a function to use any date range:

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def mthStList(start_date, end_date):
    stdt_list = []
    cur_date = start_date.replace(day=1) # sets date range to start of month
    while cur_date <= end_date:
        stdt_list.append(cur_date)
        cur_date += relativedelta(months=+1)
    return stdt_list

mthStList(date(2012, 5, 26), date.today())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime 
import calendar 
import re
from datetime import date

def findDay(date): 
    born = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y %m %d').weekday() 
    return (calendar.day_name[born]) 

def hyp(j):    
    no_hyphens = re.sub('-',' ',str(j))
    return no_hyphens

def send(year_start):    
    date = hyp(year_start)
    print (date)
    print(findDay(date))

epoch_year = 2019
for i in range(1,13):
    year_start = date(epoch_year, i, 1)
    send(year_start)
```

Comment: When adding a new answer to a question that already has many answers, it is helpful to readers if you add even a small amount of text that explains how your answer differs from others, and what it does to improve on them.  Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as @Andrew's answer, but much faster:

```
dates = []
date = datetime.date.today()
while date.year < 2015:
    if date.day == 1:
        dates.append(date)
        # I added the following line:
        date += datetime.timedelta(days=27)
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Using force, but not being brutal.